# How to fix "blocked by CORS policy" when POST request to different port in Angular 7?

Tags: node.js, angular7

I'm trying to post request to node server "http://localhost:3000" from 
 "http://localhost:4200".

//Client Side - Angular 7

```
  let obs = this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/testpost',
    {
      "data":  "test123"
    }
    );
    obs.subscribe((response)=> console.log(response),
    (error)  => console.log("Error" ,error)
  );
```

//Server Side - Node Js

```
app.post('/testpost',function(req,res){
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.json({"responseCode" : 0,"response":req.query['data']});
});
```

I expect data from server but CORS policy error occurs

Comment: you need to set the content type on the client to application/json.   on the server the easiest way is to use CORS middleware and bodyparser for JSON

Answer (score 0):

Install the CORS middleware via

> npm i cors
>
> npm i @types/cors --save-dev (for the types in typescript)

And then add the following to you server file

```
import cors = require('cors')
app.use(
    cors(),
    express.json(),
    express.urlencoded({extended:false})
)
```